# Script to post to a google calendar from google form. Stuck in authorization loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm totally new to google apps scripts and trying to write a simple script that will pull info from a google spreadsheet when a new row is added to it from a form and use that info to make a new calendar event. Here's what I have so far (calendar and spreadsheet IDs removed).

```
    function addToCalendar() {

  //Get the spreadsheet by its id, set it as active, then select the last row to always have the most recent

  var getByID = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS ID");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(getByID);
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[1];
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Declare variables for the required text fields and set them equal to corresponding cell values
  var name = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var subject = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  var date = (sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue()).toDateString();
  var startTime = date + " " + (sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue()).toTimeString();
  var endTime = date + " " + (sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue()).toTimeString();

  //Call the calendar and add the event
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('CALENDAR ID');
  var event = calendar.createEvent(name, 
                       new Date(startTime), 
                       new Date(endTime)
                      );
  Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

When I run the code I am asked to authorize the app repeatedly in a loop. The trigger is set to run the function from spreadsheet on form submit. I think the problem may have something to do with how I'm calling the spreadsheet and then setting it active but I tried to copy that code directly from the documentation. Another issue may be with formatting the dates as this part was confusing as well (relatively new to js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve dates from a spreadsheet they are already JavaScript Date objects, you can use [date methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to get what you want, see example code below.

Also, no need to activate a spreadsheet to work on it, `openById` is sufficient.

```
function addToCalendar() {

  //Get the spreadsheet by its id, set it as active, then select the last row to always have the most recent
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS ID");
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];// 0 for first sheet, 1 for second ...
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Declare variables for the required text fields and set them equal to corresponding cell values
  var name = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var subject = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  var date = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue();
  var startTime = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  var endTime = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth()-1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  var startTime = new Date(sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue().setFullYear(year,month,day));// keep hours and minutes but set day and month
  var endTime = new Date(sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue().setFullYear(year,month,day));// keep hours and minutes but set day and month
  Logger.log('start : '+startTime+'  -  end : '+endTime);
  //Call the calendar and add the event (uncomment below when you have filled with your own calendar data)
//  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('CALENDAR ID');
//  var event = calendar.createEvent(name, startTime,endTime);
//  Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```